# Question about properties of eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am working with eigenvalues and vaguely remembered learning these specific, notable properties of eigenvalues, but I can't fully remember it. If you know what I'm talking about, please let me know, and maybe expand on why it works and how to extend it to larger matrices.

Given $2\times2$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a&b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,$ we know:

$\lambda_1+\lambda_2=?$

$\lambda_1\lambda_2=?$

My question is what are these question marks supposed to be, because I'm pretty sure it tells us something.

Comment: Surely you can consult your text?

Comment: It was a trick I learned from a friend haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace, i.e the sum of the diagonal elements $a+d$.

The product of the eigenvalues is equal to the determinant of the matrix $ad-bc$.